# Angular when page gets refresh how to make loaclstorage values null

Tags: local-storage, angular4-forms

Here im storing pagination values in localstorage.When my page is Refresh how can i make localStorage value to null

```
localStorage.setItem('Hello',page);
```

when my page refresh it should null

Comment: Why are you saving this in local storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could clear the storage on page load with something like

> localStorage.clear(); // Will clear ALL keys

or

> localStorage.removeItem('Hello'); // Will clear only 'Hello'